# CSS changes on Scroll when using handsontable.js

Tags: javascript, excel, web, render, handsontable

im using a handsontable https://handsontable.com/ on a webpage.

```
  var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
                    data: datatable,
                    colHeaders: true,
                    rowHeaders: true,
                    width: 600,



                    licenseKey: "non-commercial-and-evaluation",
                });
```

Now I want to dynalically highlight some cells by changing it's background color. Like this:

```
 var dataElements = document.querySelectorAll('.handsontable td');

 if (row_attr == "ALL") {
            for (var k = row * numberOfCols; k < (row + 1) * numberOfCols; k++) {
                dataElements[k].style.backgroundColor = color;
            }
        }
```

Thia works fine but if a scroll further down on the page and go back up to that cell it is not colored anymore.

Is anyone familliar with the handsontable.js ?

I guess the table dynamically renders the part of the table that is displayed but I'm not sure.

Comment: Handsontable is re-rendering each cell when you scroll. Use your custom renderer to keep your style when scrolling. See : https://handsontable.com/docs/7.4.2/demo-custom-renderers.html